# Is there a way to list names of all shared memory objects?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost, shared-memory

As one can access the shared memory object using boost's `find` method of `managed_shared_memory`, like:

```
res = segment.find<MyType> ("name");
```

Is there a way to list the names of all shared memory objects defined in a certain segment? I need it for debugging but didn't find boost API for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `named_begin()` and `named_end()` iterators.

A small demo that creates various vectors of strings with random lengths and reports back how many it found:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9554870bffa4a9dc)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

using Mem = bip::managed_mapped_file;
template <typename T = void>
using Alloc = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<
        bip::allocator<T, Mem::segment_manager> >;
using String = boost::container::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char> >;
template <typename T>
using Vector = boost::container::vector<T, Alloc<T> >;

int main() {
    auto mf = Mem(bip::open_or_create, "test.bin", 20ul<<30);
    std::cout << "Named #" << mf.get_segment_manager()->get_num_named_objects() << "\n";

    using Container = Vector<String>;

    for (auto to_create: {"foo", "bar", "qux"}) {
        auto& c = *mf.find_or_construct<Container>(to_create)(mf.get_segment_manager());
        auto n = rand()%10;
        for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
            c.emplace_back(std::to_string(i*i));
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Named #" << mf.get_segment_manager()->get_num_named_objects() << "\n";

    for (auto it = mf.named_begin(); it != mf.named_end(); ++it) {
        std::string_view name(it->name(), it->name_length());
        std::cout << "Item " << name << " has " <<
            reinterpret_cast<Container const*>(it->value())->size() << " elements\n";
    }

}
```

Prints

```
Named #0
Named #3
Item bar has 6 elements
Item foo has 3 elements
Item qux has 7 elements
```

Of course, I don't encourage using the `reinterpret_cast`. Use the `find_or_construct` interface like you would normally.